# Angular 2 - ngModel with dynamic object/properties

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-ngmodel

In my TS file I am dynamically creating the properties on my `selectedValsObj` object like this:

```
private selectValsObj: any = {};

setSelectedValsObj(sectionsArr) {
  sectionsArr.forEach(section => {
    section.questions.forEach(questionObj => {
      if (questionObj.type === 'drop-down') {
        this.selectValsObj[questionObj.questionId] = { selected: questionObj.answerDetails[0] };
      }
    })
  });
}
```

In my HTML I want to bind the `[ngModel]` on my inputs to the properties on the `selectValsObj` object.  I have tried this but have had no luck:

```
<div *ngFor="let question of section.questions">
    <div class="drop-down-question" *ngIf="question?.type === 'drop-down'">
        <select class="q-select"
                [(ngModel)]="selectValsObj[questionId].selected" // <== doesnt work either**
                // [(ngModel)]="selectValsObj[{{ questionId }}].selected" // <== doesnt work**
                name="answerForQuestion{{ question?.questionId }}">
            <option *ngFor="let answer of question?.answerDetails"
                [ngValue]="answer">
                    {{ answer?.value }}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I set the `ngModel` in my HTML to a dynamically created property in my TS file?

Comment: it should be `[(ngModel)]="selectValsObj [questionObj.questionId].selected"`

Answer (score 5):

I tried to replicate the situation but in the code, you have posted seem to be multiple problems.

1. property `selectValsObj` is declared as `private` but you are trying to use it in the template
2. in the template you are trying to iterate over `section.questions` but I don't see it defined anywhere else but in the `setSelectedValsObj` method forEach local scope
3. You might be using your data wrong because of lacking type definitions

This is your code as I understood it and added typedefs

```
interface QuestionModel {
  type: string;
  questionId: string;
  answerDetails: string[];
}

const MOCK_DATA = [
  {
    questions: [{
      type: 'drop-down',
      questionId: '42',
      answerDetails: ['wololo'],
    }],
  },
];


@Component(...)
export class ProductsComponent {
  selectValsObj: { [key: string]: { selected: string } } = {};

  constructor() {
    this.setSelectedValsObj(MOCK_DATA);
  }

  setSelectedValsObj(sectionsArr: { questions: QuestionModel[] }[]) {
    sectionsArr.forEach(section => {
      section.questions.forEach(questionObj => {
        if (questionObj.type === 'drop-down') {
          this.selectValsObj[questionObj.questionId] = {selected: questionObj.answerDetails[0]};
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

After you check if the type definitions are as you originally intended (and use it properly) you will prevent a lot of bugs.

Also, consider using more declarative approach, `map` and `filter` your data instead of using `forEach` in a method.

Answer (score 1):

For the following line in your HTML code:

```
[(ngModel)]="selectValsObj[questionId].selected"
```

If you didn't define the `questionId` as a variable that has a value anywhere in your ts file, then that can be the problem.

If you want to get `questionId` of each `question` in your `section.questions` list that you are looping on you can try to make it as follows:

```
[(ngModel)]="selectValsObj[question.questionId].selected"
```

I have made a simple example, you can find it [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/WiwgDxWmXkRCLbLX7OWv?p=preview) (in the `src/app.ts`) with different working cases. I hope it can help.

Answer (score 1):

```
(click)="toggle(address.id)"
  *ngIf="action[address.id]"
```

in ts file:

```
action: any = {};
```

in toggle method,

```
this.action[addressId] = !this.action[addressId];
```

Answer (score 0):

- It is not very clear what you are trying to achieve.
- I assume you
  are trying to dynamically build a page with questions and answers in
  combo-box if it is of type '**drop-down**'.
- You are also trying to
  capture the selected answer.

if so... below code snippet can help.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

interface Question {
  questionStr: string;
  questionId: string;
  type: string;
  answers: Array<string>;
  selectedAnswer: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';

  selectValsArr: Array<Question> = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setSelectedValsObj([
      {
         questionStr : 'Question1',
         questionId: 'Q01',
         type: 'drop-down',
         answers: ['Q1Ans1', 'Q1Ans2', 'Q1Ans3'],
         selectedAnswer: null
      },
      {
        questionStr: 'Question2',
        questionId: 'Q02',
        type: 'drop-down',
        answers: ['Q2Ans1', 'Q2Ans2', 'Q2Ans3'],
        selectedAnswer: null
      },
    ]);
  }


  setSelectedValsObj(sectionsArr: Array<Question>) {
    sectionsArr.forEach(section => {
      if (section.type === 'drop-down') {
        this.selectValsArr.push(section);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

and **HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let question of selectValsArr">
  <h3>{{question.questionStr}}</h3>
  <div class="drop-down-question">
    <select [(ngModel)]="question.selectedAnswer">
      <option value="">Select an Answer</option>
      <option *ngFor="let ans of question.answers" [ngValue]="ans"> {{ans}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<br>
<h2>Selected Answer</h2>

<div *ngFor="let question of selectValsArr">
    <span>{{question.questionStr}}</span>
    <span>&nbsp; &nbsp; - &nbsp; {{question.selectedAnswer}}</span>
</div>
```